# Setting up PHPStorm with TortoiseSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn, installation, phpstorm, visualsvn-server

I have installed the VisualSVN server on our Windows Server 2008 plus i did connect it with Dreamweaver on other client PC.

so Dreamweaver is ready to go.
But i also want to setup the PHPStorm on other Client PC with that visualSVN.

But i want PHPStorm to use TortoiseSVN to connect to VisualSVN.

I can't find its settings page, i am new to PHPStorm, Especially to this Subversion Control thingy.

I also searched for this over web, but i cant find specific PHPStorm Setup procedure with TortoiseSVN or connecting to VisualSVN Server.

Can anyone Guide me to the Right Path?

Comment: SVN client is built into PhpStorm, you don't need and can't use an external client (except for the optional acceleration feature).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's impossible to connect PhpStorm to TortoiseSVN as they are doing the same thing.

Then you have two choices :

- Connect PhpStorm to your SVN server with his built-in feature.
- Or use TortoiseSVN

I'll recommande using PhpStorm feature as it is directly in the IDE.

You can find documentation here : https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/using-subversion-integration.html

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is not entirely accurate.  It is possible to use TortoiseSVN through PHPStorm's External Tools configurations.  This does not integrate into the project navigation directly, but does allow direct file manipulation (and allows for 'blame' support - something PHPStorm's subversion lacks).

Similar functionality is used in [eclipse](http://www.functor.be/wiki/index.php/Eclipse_External_Tools).

*Example, paths/macros's might need to be altered:*

- **Name**: SVN View Log
- **Program**: C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe
- **Parameters**: /command:log /path:"$FileName$"
- **Working Directory**: $FileDir$

Answer (score 4):

You can actually do this very easily and it will work inside PHP Storm 8.  Install Tortoise SVN and make sure to include "Command Line Tools" as part of the installation.  Then you can enable External client and select the "svn.exe" as the executable.  This will enable SVN 1.8 format and still work within the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

- Install TortoiseSVN
- Install CollabNet Subversion with command-line binaries (32 or 64-bit)

  [image]

  - Open phpStorm
  - File > Settings > Version Control > Subversion
  - Set path for your SVN command line client

e.g.

> C:\Program Files\CollabNet\Subversion Client\svn.exe

Tortoise can be used as a GUI tool, whereas CollabNet Subversion command line tool can be used with phpStorm. Enjoy!